# What client-side events does the standard ASP.NET GridView have?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, client-side

I've implemented a GridView that is within an UpdatePanel whose trigger is the GridViews SelectedIndexChanged event. As expected, it works very slow. I'd instead like to handle this on the client-side, but cannot find enough information on what client-side events a GridView supports. Can anyone point out any references where this information may be available?

EDIT: Even if anyone knows any client-side events off the top of their heads, I'd be interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What client-side events does the standard ASP.NET GridView have?

I'd be happy to be proven wrong by another response, but... none? It's a server-side object with no client-side javascript object representation. This is typical of most standard ASP.NET WebForms controls.

Drop a GridView on a WebForm and add a column `<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" />` Client-side, this looks like: `<td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Select$0&#39;)">Select</a></td>`

There's no client-side event on any object that you can handle, it's just an anchor with a javascript snippet calling a postback. If you're wanting something more fancy, you're going to have to bake something yourself, like - http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewrea/archive/2008/08/04/gridview-row-click-selection-via-clientside-code.aspx

The *alternative*, is to move to another ASP.NET WebForms "Grid" control. I know the DevExpress grid for example has a rich client-side object model. I'm almost certain Telerik has similar, and there's probably a few others out there.

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks! I've tried to do this using a DevExpress Grid and it does have quite a bit of client side support, making my application much faster.

Comment: Yes, I've used the DevExpress Grid myself a bit and it's pretty powerful. Just remember that when you're wanting to do client-side operations with it, head for the JS object representation of it -`ASPxClientGridView` - http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxGridViewScriptsASPxClientGridViewtopic Of particular interest is its `PerformCallback` method, and the server-side handlers on the `ASPxGridView` object - `CustomCallback` and `CustomDataCallback`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I use this to create client-side events for the built-in buttons in GridView.

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        MyCommon.GridButtonClientClick(gvLookup, "gclick()");
}

public static void GridButtonClientClick(GridView g, String function)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in g.Rows)
    {
        Control x = gvr.Cells[0].Controls[0];
        LinkButton y = (LinkButton)x;
        y.OnClientClick = function;
    }
}
```